# Download an exe file and run

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, exe

I've been trying to make it where I can download a .exe file from the web, read it, and write it to a file locally,  and then execute.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.ddlands.com/downloads/Calc.exe");
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    File file = new File("analbread"+".exe");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        bw.write(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
    Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("analbread" + ".exe");
    System.out.println(r.toString());
    System.out.println("WORKS!");
```

Although I know that doesn't work due to using BufferedWriter, and i'm not sure if it runs the exe.

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the output of the process? If so, use r.getInputSream()

Comment: I want to download an exe, save it locally, and then run it, all through java without user interaction. My code is not working when I tested it, I'm not able to get a copy of the exe from a server

Comment: @CheenarOrangez u got this working, if yes please let me know. I have similar requirment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the downloading part, you'll need to use binary read/write. See this for further details: [Working unbuffered streams](http://codeisland.org/2012/working-unbuffered-streams/).

For the executing part, the problem is that the [`Runtime.exec()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) can't launch your executable file.

At least under Linux (I can't test it on Windows), you'll need the full path to the executable file (or use `./[file]` when the file is in the same directory as your application) to be able to execute it.

Only giving the command works for executables which are part of your systems [PATH-variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ClickOnce: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce
We've used that succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used the following with good results to run command line scripts. You can create a batch script that runs the executable or run it directly using the exec method - probably pass "cmd ". This opens a command prompt from which you can run anything.

```
public static void runScript(String batchFile, boolean waitForExit0, int retryTime)
{
    try
    { 
        String runString = "cmd /c start " + (waitForExit0?"/wait ":"") + "/MIN " + batchFile;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runString); //   /c start /wait

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                int exit = p.exitValue();
                if (exit == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("completed: " + runString);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                String s = "";
            }

            Thread.sleep(retryTime);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String s = "";
    }
}
```