# download exe file from the given URL

Tags: java

i have an exe file at a specific URL. now i want to download it in my PC. so i can do this?? i can stream a txt file to save it in PC but unable to do this if its an exe file

```
URL url = new URL("http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_117110776");   
url.openConnection();   
    try (InputStream reader = url.openStream()) {   
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("t12.txt");  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];  
        int bytesRead = 0;  
        while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)  
        {    
           writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  
           buffer = new byte[153600];  
        }  
        writer.close();  
    }
```

the URL where my exe resides is " http://jobnews.netii.net/calc.exe"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download an exe file and run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536963/download-an-exe-file-and-run)

Comment: define "unable". What happens? Also, why are you recreating your buffer at each iteration? And if the URL is `http://jobnews.netii.net/calc.exe`, why does the code use the URL `http://torrentz.eu/announcelist_117110776`? And why do you save an exe file to a .txt file?